# Playing Kinect's video and audio feeds in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, kinect

I saw the Velocity channel's "Inside West Coast Customs" this week featuring the construction of [Microsoft's (Channel 9) Project Detroit](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/detroit), and was really impressed by the ability to play the Kinect's video and audio feeds from Windows Phone 7. I decided to put together a little utility of my own using the same principle, but am unable to find any code samples on how to accomplish this.

Can anyone here provide me with a code sample, or point me in the right direction? Microsoft is planning to release some portions of their source code from Project Detroit eventually, but I'm hoping this has already been done elsewhere.

I appreciate any help you guys can provide. Thank you!

Best regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Kinect Service [Kinect Service](http://kinectservice.codeplex.com/)

They used windows phone sockets to relay the data. It even includes a sample windows phone app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I actually discovered the Kinect Service about a week ago and it works well.